# Django: List item.id as field attr?

Tags: django, modelform, templatetag

In my template I have :

```
{% for link in solution_list %}
 <form id="marked_solved_form{{link.id}}" action="" method="post">                                                                     
 {{mark_solved_form.is_solution}}                                                                                                      
 {% csrf_token %}                                                                                                                      
 <label for="id_is_solution{{link.id}}">test form</label>                                    
 <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}"/>                                                                         
 </form>                                 
 {% endfor %}
```

is_solution is just a booleanfield for a checkbox that user's can set.

The problem I am facing is that all the forms populate correctly with id's like id="marked_solved_form3" except for the {{mark_solved_form.is_solution}}. I thought I could just go to the modelform and edit the attributes:

```
class PostMarkedSolved(ModelForm):                                                                                                          
 class Meta:                                                                                                                             
     model = MarkedSolved                                                                                                                

 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                    
     super(PostMarkedSolved, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                                                                             
     #self.fields['is_solution'].queryset = Factory.objects.all()                                                                        
     self.fields['is_solution'].widget.attrs={'onchange':'this.form.submit();', 'class':'testing{{link.id}}', 'id':'testing{{link.id}}'}
```

So far so good. Except when the form loads, I get the following for every checkbox in every list form:

```
<input name="is_solution" type="checkbox" class="testing{{link.id}}" onchange="this.form.submit();" id="testing{{link.id}}">
```

It's as though django is ignoring the modelform is escaping template tag {{link.id}} all together. Ideally it would return for each form instance something like:

```
  <td>
  <form id="marked_solved_form3" action="" method="post">
  <input name="is_solution" type="checkbox" class="testing3" onclick="this.form.submit();" id="testing3" />
  <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='bwuXYhSpQA8yEOEPSaCt3wAANC0kR7CE' /></div>
  <label for="id_is_solution3" onclick="this.form.submit();">test form</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/task/1"/>
  </form>
  </td>

  <td>
  <form id="marked_solved_form4" action="" method="post">
  <input name="is_solution" type="checkbox" class="testing4" onclick="this.form.submit();" id="testing4" />
  <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='bwuXYhSpQA8yEOEPSaCt3wAANC0kR7CE' /></div>
  <label for="id_is_solution4" onclick="this.form.submit();">test form</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/task/1"/>
  </form>
  </td>
```

I even went as far as to install django-widget-tweaks (Which is awesome, btw!), and tried doing:

```
{{mark_solved_form.is_solution|attr:"id:id_is_solution{{link.id}}"}}
```

However that choked because it cannot handle {{link.id}} within another template tag. :( Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The template isn't able to render those variables placed in the `__init__` method. You should be able to access the model instance through `self.instance` and add the correct id's in the `__init__` method by doing doing the following:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                    
    super(PostMarkedSolved, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                                                                             
    self.fields['is_solution'].widget.attrs={
        'onchange':'this.form.submit();',
        'class':'testing{0}', 'id':'testing{1}'.format(self.instance.id, self.instance.id)
    }
```

[Hidden in Django's docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method)

> Also, a model form instance bound to a model object will contain a self.instance attribute that gives model form methods access to that specific model instance.

Comment: Unfortunately. since I have multiple instances of the input on the same page, when I submit one, it submits them all and changes all the id's. I think I will try something else and the form solution does not to be the right approach. I really appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong approach. You should use separate forms with prefixes, or even better use a formset.